# Why there is a need to trigger to see Crystal frequency with persistent screen ? Why can't continuous run mode of scope does the overlap correctly?

Tags: crystal, probe, jitter

Thanks Guys. I think I did not explain my question correctly. Getting dumb day by day. I am probing SMD 25MHz XO output with 500MHz probe. When my Scope is in continuous run mode, I see my persistent screen all over the place. Time scare properly adjusted for 1 cycle. But when i trigger it at any level, Persistent screen clears off and give me exact one cycle one top of another. My question was why we need trigger in this case. Isnt the crystal output needs to be stable in the first place ?

Comment: Your description does not match your title. Provide more information on your test setup.

Comment: Watching waveform directly from quartz oscillator you should use special probs for oscilloscope. Regular probes does not fit for that task.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I think I did not explain my question correctly. Getting dumb day by day.

Comment: You now changed the question, which may invalidate the answers. If you don't trigger on the signal, the scope starts sampling the signal at any arbitrary point and because they are not aligned you see the signal all over the place. If you do trigger on the signal, the scope starts sampling always on the same point, e.g. rising edge of midpoint, and thus all captures are aligned.

Answer (score 3):

*One single cycle on the oscilloscope screen?* You're more likely to see jitter of the oscilloscope's trigger circuit than jitter of the oscillator-under-test. If your persistent screen is a mess, it is unlikely that the trigger circuit is properly operating.

Older oscilloscopes' timebase is likely less stable than a properly operating crystal oscillator-under-test. Modern oscilloscopes use a *crystal-referenced timebase* that is more likely to resolve a test-oscillator's jitter. Your oscilloscope manual offers a clue which kind of timebase your oscilloscope has: a timebase **accuracy** of a few percent suggests old technology. Timebase **accuracy** of about 50 parts-per-million suggests a crystal-referenced timebase.

Measuring jitter involves two critical oscilloscope functions:

- trigger circuit
- timebase offset

First, get a good stable trigger on the oscillator's waveform.

- AC-couple
- low- frequency reject (if your oscilloscope has that function).

---

Example:
Not a crystal-oscillator under test, but a plain old function generator (with a *lot* more jitter than a crystal oscillator). And a modern, general-purpose oscilloscope with a crystal-referenced timebase doing the jitter measurement. The function generator has been set to 5 MHz. Sweep speed of the oscilloscope is set for 20ns/cm, displaying about 1.5 cycles:
[image: jitter measurement of 5 MHz function generator.]

The 'scope's *horizontal position* has been cranked so that the *trigger point* occurs 500 microseconds before the sweep begins. That means 2500 cycles are not displayed before the middle of the screen. Persistence has been set for one second.
I'm expecting the oscilloscope's timebase is accurate, but nevertheless I'm unsure if the displayed jitter is a result of timebase jitter, or function generator's jitter. In measuring jitter, one is always comparing jitter of one timebase against another. In this case, I'm relatively confident that the oscilloscope's crystal-controlled timebase has less jitter than the function generator.

If there is 30ns jitter after 2500 cycles, one cycle *might* have 12 picoseconds jitter. This extrapolation is improper - that 500 us. delay acts as an averaging filter - the actual cycle-to-cycle jitter is very likely much higher than 12 ps. (see the discussion on 4 MHz crystal oscillator below).
When timebase delay was set to 200ns, and sweep rate set to 2ns/div, cycle-to-cycle jitter was barely discernible - a guess is about 800 picoseconds. Although a guess, this is a better estimate of cycle-to-cycle jitter.

---

Another example:
In this case, a 4.000 MHz crystal oscillator is probed with the same general-purpose oscilloscope. This is a tough test, because jitter is so much smaller.
The timebase offset has been increased to 5000 microseconds, and sweep rate is now 2 nanoseconds per division. Only the rising edge of this oscillator waveform is displayed at such fast sweep speed. Again, persistence is set to one second:

[image: 4MHz crystal oscillator jitter waveform]

Jitter appears to be about one nanosecond, 5000 microseconds after the trigger point.
One must ask in this case, "which part of this measurement system is causing jitter?".

- It could be a jittery trigger threshold inside the oscilloscope.
- It could be a jittery timebase that sets the 5000 us delay.
- It could be jitter in the 4 MHz oscillator being probed.

So the 1ns jitter measurement is suspect, and should be regarded with suspicion. In this case, there are 20,000 cycles of the 4 MHz waveform in the 0.005 second span between trigger point and display. That's 50 femtoseconds jitter for each cycle of the oscillator-under-test.
This "jitter" extrapolation is improper -  extrapolating 1ns jitter back to 50 femtoseconds is unfair. The 0.005 measurement period is a sorta averaging filter that differs from the usual R.M.S. jitter measurement cycle-to-cycle. No doubt, the accepted way of measuring jitter (cycle-to-cycle) would be considerably larger than this unfair extrapolation of 1 nanosecond back to 50 femtoseconds.
I was unable to extend the 0.005 second timespan offset (my oscilloscope balked, and did a hard reset)...a good check would extend the timebase delay to 0.01 second and see if jitter doubled to 2ns.
Had I reduced timespan offset to 250 us., seeing if jitter reduced to 0.5 ns, the accuracy of that tiny jitter measurement from the oscilloscope screen would suffer.
 This oscilloscope is simply unable to measure cycle-to-cycle jitter on this crystal oscillator using this method.

As a sanity check, this crystal oscillator was measured with a frequency counter. The least significant digit (representing 1 Hz) changed with temperature, but from one measurement period to the next, was stable. That suggests after one second, jitter is less than one cycle (250 ns). That frequency counter can only resolve jitter of 250 ns. or more. After one-second time period, you'd better call it "drift", not "jitter".

Answer (score 1):

Your onboard crystal and your function generator are ***not synchronous*** (i.e. they don't measure time with the same clock). Even if you set the frequency arbitrarily close, there is no fixed phase relation. So when viewing in Continuous Auto Trigger mode on a scope the other waveform will be all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to measure Crystal Oscillator jitter is to use a precise method, unlike your noisy trigger method.

If the oscillator is not operating properly due to a rough layout with noise pickup, then the obvious issues need to be eliminated. The repetitive output should look like a textbook waveform with the alternate transition zoomed out with a delayed sweep. Adjust AC trigger to 0V ought to be sufficient for a 50% duty factor.

A more precise method uses a spectrum analyzer to look at close-in phase noise in a defined bandwidth or dB down from fundamental.

Other methods use a precision time interval counter or the clock itself to use a PLL to measure phase noise.

However, if your Xtal OSC is more unstable than your signal generator, we need more details.